# Rails helper in view - How to have the result of a helper rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This is my very first question about Rails. I am exploring it for just a month.

In a view, I have a very simple condition to apply on an number to decide to wrap it by a `span` with either the `.negative` or `.positive` class (making it red or green).

The below code is working... But is to be reused a lot.

```
.col-3
  - if item.amount.positive?
    %span.positive
      = item.amount
  - else
    %span.negative
      = item.amount
```

So in order to be DRY, I want to make it a "helper" in `application_helper.rb`. I found this [How to use Haml in your helpers](https://makandracards.com/makandra/42413-how-to-use-haml-in-your-helpers) and wrote a helper as follows:

```
def amountColor(x)
  puts "============================================"
  - if x.positive?
      puts "POSITIVE"
      render_haml <<-HAML, amount: x
        %span.positive= amount
      HAML
    else
      puts "NEGATIVE"
      render_haml <<-HAML, amount: x
        %span.negative= amount
      HAML
    end
  puts "============================================"
end
```

And I attempt to call it like this:

```
.col-3
  -amountColor(item.amount)
  Nothing displays just above this line.
```

In the server's console, I get:

```
  Rendering pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application
============================================
NEGATIVE
<span class='negative'>-100</span>
============================================
  Rendered pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 1856)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.haml (Duration: 2.6ms | Allocations: 2379)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 13435)
```

Which makes me think the helper is called and does its job quite right... But the `span` is not rendered.

Now if I try (`=` instead of `-`):

```
.col-3
  = amountColor(item.amount)
```

It renders the `span` as text...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to actually render the HTML, you will need to use [html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)

```
= amountColor(item.amount).html_safe
```

You could also just inline it and remove the need for the helper altogether:

```
- klass = item.amount.positive ? 'positive' : 'negative'
%span{class: klass}= item.amount
```

Comment: I knew that was something simple! Thanks ;)

Comment: Added a small addition about inline assignment